# Override style display in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this at the top of my document:

```
var set = document.querySelector("#container");
set.style.display = isSet;
```

`isSet` is either "none" or "block".

I want to override it here:

```
function mainUpdate(type) {
if (type == "music") {
isplaying ? document.querySelector("#container").style.display = block : document.querySelector("#container").style.display = isSet;
```

But when `isSet` is "none" by default, it does not change it to "block" in the mainUpdate function. If I remove the code at the top of my document it shows a weird animation in the mainUpdate type where it changes from block to none. So basically I want `#container` to have a default style which is either "none" or block", in the mainUpdate function I want to change the style to "block" when `isplaying` is true and otherwise it should go back to `isSet`, how can I achieve this?

Comment: `block` should be a string, not a variable (unless you've defined).

Comment: where do you declare `isSet` ?

Comment: `document.querySelector("#container").style.display = isplaying ? 'block' : isSet`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see block wasn't a string, isSet is a value from a .plist file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `block` must be a string. Otherwise it is searching for the variable `block` which is undefined. Second, you should use 'camelCase' when naming variables that are composed by 2 or more words, for example `isplaying` should be `isPlaying`.

Third, if you declare `set` as a global variable, why not use it inside the function as well ? Makes the code more readable.

Fourth, use `let` and `const` for variable declaration. Read here under Declarations -> [let and const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) and you could read some articles regarding the [let const vs var](https://dev.to/sarah_chima/var-let-and-const--whats-the-difference-69e)

I made a simple example where `isPlaying` is first `false` then turns to `true` at a click on a button.

See below

```js
const isSet = 'none'
const set = document.querySelector("#container");
const button = document.querySelector("button");
let isPlaying = false;
set.style.display = isSet;
button.onclick = function() {
  isPlaying = true
  isPlaying ? set.style.display = 'block' : set.style.display = isSet;
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

</div>
<button>
Click to show the container
</button>
```